# GitHubにある複数のリモートリポジトリのソースコードに対して検索を行いたい

Tags: git, github

#### やりたいこと

目的は、複数あるリモートリポジトリに対して毎回検索ワードをいれて検索するのが大変なため、検索ワードをいれたら複数のリポジトリに対して自動で検索を行えるバッチなどを作成したいと考えてます。
そのためgithubにあるリモートリポジトリのソースコードに対して、windowsのコマンドなどを用いて検索を行いたいと考えています。

#### やったこと

git grepコマンドなどでgitのURLからリモートのソースコードを検索行えるかなと思ったのですがうまくいかない状況です。

#### 理想

ある検索ワードを入力したら、想定されるすべてのリモートリポジトリに対して検索を行い、検索結果を一覧化されたファイルをローカルに出力されるイメージをしています。
そもそものやり方含めて、よりよいやり方などがあればご教授いただければと思います。

Comment: ローカルに `clone` 済みのリポジトリが対象であれば比較的簡単に実現出来そうですが、あくまでリモートのリポジトリを対象に実現したい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: これらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Searching in multiple Github repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32119877/9014308), [Search multiple queries in multiple repos](https://github.community/t/search-multiple-queries-in-multiple-repos/119784), [REST API/リファレンス/検索](https://docs.github.com/ja/rest/reference/search), [検索クエリの構築](https://docs.github.com/ja/rest/reference/search#constructing-a-search-query)

Comment: `git remote add <リポジトリ>` とは違う、ということですよね？

Answer (score 1):

### そのまま GitHub で検索する方法

GitHub の検索では `repo:リポジトリ名` という書き方をすることで検索対象のリポジトリを指定することができ、更にこれは複数指定すると OR 検索されます。参考: https://docs.github.com/ja/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories

このためたとえば `foo repo:torvalds/linux repo:llvm/llvm-project` のように検索すると https://github.com/torvalds/linux と https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project から `foo` について検索する、というクエリになります: https://github.com/search?q=foo+repo%3Atorvalds%2Flinux+repo%3Allvm%2Fllvm-project&type=code

GitHub 上にある複数のリポジトリに対して検索したいのであれば、とりあえずこれでおおよそ解決すると思います。

### ローカル環境に git pull してきて検索する方法

そのままリモートリポジトリを pull して良いのであれば、単に `git pull` してローカルにファイルを置いた上で、好きなように PowerShell の `Select-String` なり bash の `grep` なりを使えば良いです。

Comment: 詳しく説明いただきありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

GitHub限定ですが、WebブラウザでGitHubのリポジトリを開いた状態で `.` を入力すると `github.dev` にページ遷移し、ブラウザ内でVisual Studio Codeが立ち上がります。
Visual Studio Codeの使用経験があれば、そのまま検索などが行えます。

Comment: なるほど、そういう方法もあるのですね
ありがとうございます！