# windowsバッチで複数のリポジトリを検索したい

Tags: git, batch-file, コマンドプロンプト

#### やりたいこと

目的は、ローカルにプルした各種のリポジトリに対して一括で同じ検索ワードをまとめて検索できるようにしテキストファイルとして出力したいです。

#### 理想

ある検索ワードを入力したら、ローカルにプルしたリモートリポジトリに対して検索を行い、検索結果を一覧化されたファイルをローカルに出力されるイメージをしています。

以下のようなディレクトリのリストがあった場合に、すべてのリポジトリ（ディレクトリ）に対してコマンドで「git grep　”検索ワード”」を実施し、どのリポジトリで検索したのかなどもテキストファイルに出力できたかや検索されたソースコードの一部を出力されたファイルを一覧化してtextファイルなどに保存したいと考えています。
初歩的な質問で大変恐縮ですがご教授いただけるとありがたいです。

```
C:¥git/repositories_aaa
C:¥git/repositories_bbb
C:¥git/repositories_ccc
C:¥git/repositories_ddd
```

Comment: 整合性に乱れがあるようですが、入力ミスでしょうか？ 「ローカルにプルした各種のリポジトリに対して」と「想定されるすべてのリモートリポジトリに対して」

Comment: やりたいことが書かれているだけで、試したことや何が分からないのかが明確になっていない印象です。(複数じゃなくて単一のリポジトリなら検索できるのか？等) / ローカルとリモートではアプローチが変わってくると思うので、その辺りを明確にするために [前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/80872) でコメントしました。結局前回の質問と回答のやり取りは無駄になったということでしょうか？

Comment: ちなみに`C:\git`フォルダ直下にはこの4つのリポジトリだけがあるという条件ですか？ それ以外にもリポジトリ/リポジトリではないディレクトリ/ファイル等は有りますか？ 対象リポジトリ以外がある場合は選択/指定方法に希望がありますか？

Comment: 前質問でも気になっていたのですが、検索して何がしたいのでしょうか？ 検索そのものが目的ではなく、[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/4236)に陥っているのではないかと考えています。

Comment: みなさまコメントありがとうございます!質問内容がわかりにくく申し訳ないです… >やりたいことが書かれているだけで、試したことや何が分からないのかが明確になっていない印象です 指摘ありがとうございます、文面を推敲しますmm

Comment: >C:\gitフォルダ直下にはこの4つのリポジトリだけがあるという条件ですか？ それ以外にもリポジトリ/リポジトリではないディレクトリ/ファイル等は有りますか？ 対象リポジトリ以外がある場合は選択/指定方法に希望がありますか？ はい、他のリポジトリが存在するため対象のリポジトリを指定して検索を行いたいと考えています

Answer (score 1):

「Windows バッチで」とありますが Git が使える環境であれば Git Bash 等をインストール済みでしょうから、Unix コマンドを使った方が簡単だと思います。

リポジトリが一カ所のフォルダ以下にまとめてあるのであれば、`find` コマンド、`xargs` コマンド、そして `grep` コマンドを組み合わせて以下のように実行することができます。

```sh
$ cd /c/git
$ find . | xargs grep -l "keyword"
```

grep の `-l` はファイル名のみを表示するオプションです。

コマンドを実行したディレクトリを起点に、キーワードを含むファイルのパスが一覧表示されるので、どのリポジトリに含まれているのかも判別可能なはずです。
テキストファイルとして結果を残したければ、そのままリダイレクトで保存してください。

Answer (score 1):

要望の通りWindowsバッチで実現すると以下のようになるでしょう。

- 対象ディレクトリに対象リポジトリ以外のリポジトリ/フォルダがあったり、そもそも対象ディレクトリが分散されている場合も考えてテキストファイルに対象リポジトリのリストを指定して`FOR`コマンドで処理する
  リストは1行1エントリで、ドライブ名から始まるフルパスで指定する
- どのリポジトリかを示す情報は、Git Bashの`sed`コマンドを使用して全ての検出した行に付ける
  git grepの結果はフルネームを指定してもリポジトリトップからの相対パスなので、その前にリポジトリのパスを挿入する
- Git BashのUnixコマンド類フォルダへのパスを追加する(既に組み込まれている場合はその行を使わなければ良い)
- git grepのオプション/検索パターンを複数(10個まで)指定出来るようにしている(常に指定するならバッチファイルの該当行にあらかじめ組み込む)

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%3" == "" (
  @ECHO パラメータが不足しています。
  @ECHO 使い方: %~n0  対象リポジトリリストファイルパス  結果出力ファイルパス  git grepオプション/パターンを1個以上10個以下
  EXIT /B 2
)
IF NOT EXIST "%~1" (
  @ECHO 対象リポジトリリストファイルが存在していません。
  EXIT /B 1
)
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%
SET TARGETREPOLIST=%~1
SET OUTPUTPATH="%~2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
SHIFT
SET GREPARGS=%0 %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
PUSHD
FOR /F %%E in (%TARGETREPOLIST%) do (
    CALL :REPOGREP %%E
)
POPD
EXIT /B 0

:REPOGREP
CD /D "%~1"
@ECHO ==========  "%~1"  処理中  ==========
SET REPODIR=%~1
SET REPODIR=%REPODIR:\=\/%
git grep %GREPARGS% | sed -e "/^-*$/!s/^/%REPODIR%\//" >>%OUTPUTPATH%
EXIT /B 0
```

---

対象リポジトリをテキストファイルではなく、指定したディレクトリ以下全てとする場合は：

```
FOR /F %%E in (%TARGETREPOLIST%) do (
```

の部分を以下にすれば良いでしょう。

```
FOR /D %%E in (%TARGETREPOLIST%\*) do (
```

---

どのリポジトリかを示す情報を、全ての行に付けるのではなく出力結果に区切りの行として入れる形にする場合は：

```
SET REPODIR=%~1
SET REPODIR=%REPODIR:\=\/%
git grep %GREPARGS% | sed -e "/^-*$/!s/^/%REPODIR%\//" >>%OUTPUTPATH%
```

の部分を以下にすれば良いでしょう。

```
@ECHO ==========  "%~1"  ==========>>%OUTPUTPATH%
git grep %GREPARGS% >>%OUTPUTPATH%
```

---

必要なり要望なりに応じて適宜変更してください。

Answer (score 0):

Windows 環境なので PowerShell スクリプトを使う方法も考えられます。

**grep_git_repos.ps1**

```powershell
Param([string]$topdir, [string]$searchWord)

# set encoding to UTF-8
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Depth 0 -Force $topdir |
  Where-Object {
    # get git repositories path
    if (Test-Path $_.FullName -PathType Container) {
      git -C $_.FullName rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>&1>$null
      $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0
    }
  } |
  ForEach-Object {
    # git grep for each repository
    Write-Output "Repository: $($_.Name)"
    git -C $_.FullName --no-pager grep -P -i -n --threads 4 -e $searchWord
    echo ""
  }
```

`git grep` のオプションは適宜変更してください。

**実行例**

PowerShell スクリプトを実行するために execution policies(実行ポリシー)を変更してください。

```cmd
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

コマンドプロンプトから PowerShell スクリプトを実行します。第1引数に git リポジトリが置かれているフォルダを、第2引数に検索ワードを指定します。

```cmd
cmd.exe> dir "C:\git"
 C:\git のディレクトリ

2021/08/19  21:28    <DIR>          .
2021/08/19  21:28    <DIR>          ..
2021/08/19  21:20    <DIR>          ccls
2021/08/19  21:23    <DIR>          eglot
2021/08/19  21:24    <DIR>          go-mode.el
2021/08/19  21:26    <DIR>          sshfs
2021/08/19  21:19    <DIR>          whois

cmd.exe> powershell -File grep_git_repos.ps1 "C:\git" "linux|windows" > .\matched.txt
cmd.exe> more matched.txt
Repository: ccls
CMakeLists.txt:33:# CMake sets MSVC for both MSVC and Clang(Windows)
CMakeLists.txt:35:  # Common MSVC/Clang(Windows) options
                :

Repository: eglot
.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bug_report.md:45:* Operating system:          <!-- (windows/mac osx/linux/don't know -->
README.md:90:fine on Linux and OSX but in some cases
README.md:91:[*may not work on Windows*][windows-subprocess-hang].
               :

Repository: go-mode.el
AUTHORS:23:Juergen Hoetzel <juergen@archlinux.org>
               :
```